# Print word from phrase

Tags: python, for-loop, input, split

The purpose is to print to the user first the text ‘Does your perfect winter vacation include sun-heated beach sand and salty waves or inspiring city life?’

After this it asks a number input from the user. Depending on the number, it prints that word from the text.

For example number 0 would be 'Does'.

```
print(‘Does your perfect winter vacation include sun-heated beach sand and salty waves or inspiring city life?’)
phrase = ‘Does your perfect winter vacation include sun-heated beach sand and salty waves or inspiring city life?’
ask = input('Print the word from the phrase, by your given number? ')
x = ask
y = phrase.split()
for i in y()[x]:
     print(i)
```

Comment: 1. Convert `x` to number: `x = int(ask)`. 2. Use x as an index: `print(phrase.split()[x])`. Not sure what the loop is for.

Comment: This appears to be a homework question, and is worded quite poorly. Also, there is no question stated. What issue are you having? What would you like help with?

Answer (score 0):

Several suggestions:

1. Put the phrase in a variable
2. The index "x" shall be converted to integer (because input returns a string)
3. `split` function returns a list so you cannot call it (`split()()`)
4. Using a loop will print all the letters of the first word

A simple code (without robustness in it) would look like this:

```py
phrase = 'Does your perfect winter vacation include sun-heated beach sand and salty waves or inspiring city life?'
print(phrase)
x = int(input('Print the word from the phrase, by your given number? '))
y = phrase.split()
print(y[x])
```

Comment: Hi, in StackOverflow it is usually recommended to provide text explaining the code (and not pure code). ... And also avoid just putting links to external sites as answers (because links could be broken), but that does not apply here.

Comment: First time. That said I do appreciate advising me, for future posts. Great answer with explanation, thanks